# Django celery testing: Get ETA of a result?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm writing a Django app that uses celery to schedule tasks to run at later times using `apply.async()` with an `eta` set.  I would like to test this, but I'm having trouble writing the unittests.  The main question I'm wondering is:

Given the id of a task I've created, how can I retrieve the eta that is set for it?  How do I call that info up?

I feel like this shouldn't be hard, but I've dug around the documentation and can't seem to find it....

Thanks!

Comment: I can't find an API in the code that returns the `eta`.  This is also dependent on which broker backend you're using.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right - I don't know if there's any way to pull that out given that it might be dependent on the backend.  I guess I can work around it if I have to.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: The project actually kind of went on hiatus, in part due to struggles testing this kind of thing.  I could have done it in a more involved fashion, but other things taking precedence over the project was the other thing.  I may get back to it soon, though!  Hopefully I can figure it out!